# awk regular expression to compare the file extensions

Tags: regex, file, awk

I'm trying to find the files with extensions sh, xls etc as shown in the FILTER variable below.

following is the output of ls -ltr, the output of of below script is coming as hourly_space_update.sh and kent.ksh, but I don't want .ksh file, could you please tell where I'm going wrong with my regex.

```
[root@SVRVSVN ~]# ls -ltr
total 20
-rw-r--r--  1 root sqaadmin   44 Oct  9 18:24 hourly_space_update.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 root sqaadmin    0 Oct 30 12:34 kent.ksh
-rw-r--r--  1 root sqaadmin    0 Oct 30 12:34 a.abc
-rw-r--r--  1 root sqaadmin    0 Oct 30 13:02 hh.h
#!/bin/sh

ls -ltr | awk '
BEGIN {
FILTER=".(sh|xls|xlsx|pdf)$"
}
{
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) $i = ""; sub(/^ */, "");

if(match(tolower($1),FILTER))
{
   print $1
}
}'
```

Comment: Remember that '.' does not mean "dot" in regexp. It means "any character"

Answer (score 2):

Try this regexp:

```
\.(sh|xls|xlsx|pdf)$
```

Comment: I tried that get following error: awk: cmd. line:3: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'

Comment: Adding one more back slash helped ---- \\.(sh|xls|xlsx|pdf)$

Comment: Right because when using a string in a dynamic regexp the string gets parsed twice, once when the expression is read by awk and then again when it gets tested by awk so you need to escape twice any RE metacharacters that you want treated as literals.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments I made in the answers you got so far, but more importantly - your approach of testing one of the fields will fail for file names that contain spaces, and any piped solution will fail if one of those white spaces is a newline. You should just use shell as:

```
ls -tr *.sh *.xls *.xlsx *.pdf
```

and get rid of the need for a filter at all.

If you MUST keep an awk script, though, then the way to write it is this if you can guarantee your file names don't contain any spaces:

```
ls -ltr | awk 'BEGIN{FILTER="\\.(sh|xlsx?|pdf)$"} tolower($NF) ~ FILTER { print $NF }'
```

Note that I abbreviated your RE since "xslx?" will match "xls" or "xlsx".

Before I give you a solution for file names that contain spaces or newlines, though - why are you using "ls -ltr" instead of simply "ls -tr" if you only want to process the file name?

Answer (score 1):

In bash/ksh/zsh, you can use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
ls *.{sh,xls,xlsx,pdf}
```

Also [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: This notation works in `tcsh` as well.  Oh, and **+1** for mentioning that link.

Answer (score 0):

Try with (**\bsh\b|\bxls\b|\bxlsx\b|\bpdf\b**) filter.

In you're filter you want .ksh file because it containts sh sequence.

Comment: After making the changes as suggested by you, now it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Can'tr imagine what @elrado meant with that suggestion - \b is the control-H character, no reason that should be showing up inyour file names so of course nothing now matches.

Comment: sorry :/ I was using ordinary regex syntax (\b for word boundary) I never tried it awk. I never ment to mislead you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works in my gawk 4.0.1 running under cygwin.

But how come you don't want to do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FILTER=".(sh|xls|xlsx|pdf)$"}{if(match(tolower($9),FILTER)){print $9}}'
```

This would make the for loop redundant, and clean up the code a bit. I guess output of `ls -ltr` use the same format each time you execute it. :)

Unfortunately I do not have access to a clean `awk` command for testing, but you could also try to double escape the `\\.` if that is the problem in you `awk`. A tips is to `print $1` before the if statement to make sure it contain what you expect it to be.

Comment: That is a briefer way to re-write the OPs code but it doesn't solve the problem that (s)he needs a literal "." in FILTER. It also doesn't help for file names that contain spaces.

Comment: Ahh, quite true! Filenames with spaces I did not think about. Thanks for pointing this out @EdMorton.

Comment: You're welcome. You also shouldn't count on the final field number being 9 as you can get spaces in the owner names too in some systems (e.g. cygwin) so then the file name would be in field 10 or more. So, using $NF is safer.